# Copying patch-own variable to turtle-own's

Tags: netlogo

In the following code, when I print the variable, regime, I obtain either "A" or "D", but when i print regimep or regimec I obtain ["A"] or ["D"].

The relevant code is:

```
patches-own [
regimep
]

governments-own [
regime
]

citizens-own [
regimec
]
...

to set-governments
  ask governments [
  ...
  ifelse random 100 < democracies% [set regime "D"] [set regime "A"]
  ifelse regime = "D" [set shape "star"] [set shape "circle"]
  ...
  ]
end

to set-citizens
  ask citizens [
    let x governments with [idgov = [idcit] of myself] ;; idgov is a variable of the breed governments and idcit is a variable for citizens
     set regimec [regime] of x
    ]
end

to set-patches
  ask patches [
    let x governments with [idgov = [idpat] of myself]
    set regimed [regime] of x
  ]
end
```

Where are these brackets coming from? I need to be able to print the variable without the brackets. 
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your code says inside set-patches: set regimed [regime] of x, but your patch-variable is regimep. Are you asking about regimed instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are because your variable is a list rather than a single element.

```
let x governments with [idgov = [idpat] of myself]
set regimed [regime] of x
```

`governments with [idgov = [idpat] of myself]` is an agent set.That being said, x is also an agent set.

> For an agentset, of reports a list that contains the value of the
>   reporter for each agent in the agentset (in random order).

I think you want x to be a single agent instead.

Try this

```
let x one-of governments with [idgov = [idpat] of myself]
set regimed [regime] of x
```

Similarly, regimec has the same issue.